# modify one column but print all with awk

Tags: awk

I would like to modify $2 with the following code:

```
cat file | awk '{printf "%.15f\n", $2 = 1-$2}' > new_file
```

The code does its job, it prints 15 decimals and calculates 1-n. However, it does not print the other columns. If I try to do that with the following code it does print it, but to a different line:

```
cat file | awk '{printf "%.15f\n", $2 = 1-$2; print $0}' > new_file
```

My original file:

```
752566 0.883928571428571 1 rs3094315 0
752721 0.765873015873016 1 rs3131972 0
752894 0.883928571428571 1 rs3131971 0
753541 0.268849206349206 1 rs2073813 0
```

Output:

```
752566 0.116071 1 rs3094315 0
0.116071428571429
```

Desired output (the order of the columns does not matter):

```
752566 1 rs3094315 0 0.116071428571429
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to print the new value to a formatted string, and assign that as the new value of `$2`:

```bsh
$2 = sprintf("%.15f",1-$2)
```

Then it's just a matter of printing the whole (modified) record:

```
$ awk '{$2 = sprintf("%.15f",1-$2); print}' file
752566 0.116071428571429 1 rs3094315 0
752721 0.234126984126984 1 rs3131972 0
752894 0.116071428571429 1 rs3131971 0
753541 0.731150793650794 1 rs2073813 0
```

Comment: It may be worth adding a note that since the OPs file seems to be whitespace separated, this will squash multiple whitespace between columns (if they are present). Usually not a problem, but can be unexpected (in particular for the novice).

Answer (score 2):

does it have to be awk?

```
$ cat in
752566 0.883928571428571 1 rs3094315 0
752721 0.765873015873016 1 rs3131972 0
752894 0.883928571428571 1 rs3131971 0
753541 0.268849206349206 1 rs2073813 0

$ perl -pe 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf("%.15f", 1-$1)/e' < in
752566 0.116071428571429 1 rs3094315 0
752721 0.234126984126984 1 rs3131972 0
752894 0.116071428571429 1 rs3131971 0
753541 0.731150793650794 1 rs2073813 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `dc` calculator command. The precision width is stored in the $precsn variable with default precision being set to 6. Since the ouput order needn't match so we print in the reverse order due to the LiFO nature of dc.

```
precsn=15
sed -Ee 's/\S+/[&]/4' file |
dc -e "
${precsn:-6}k
[q]sq
[n32anz2<p]sp
[?z0=q lpx 1r-1/0 nn32an pcz0=?]s?
l?x
"
0 rs3094315 1 0.116071428571429 752566
0 rs3131972 1 0.234126984126984 752721
0 rs3131971 1 0.116071428571429 752894
0 rs2073813 1 0.731150793650794 753541
```